# PHP: html select in form doesn't display value from array with for each

Tags: php, html, arrays, foreach

I have this array with a list of countries.

```
$country_list = array(
    "Afghanistan",
    "Albania",
    "Algeria",
    "Andorra",
    "Angola"
   };
```

I show these countries with a select in my form

```
<select name="countries">
  <option value=""></option>
  <?php foreach($country_list as $key => $value): ?>
  <option value="<?php $key ?>"><?php $value ?></option>
  <?php endforeach ?>
</select><br>
```

For some reason the value is showing up as an empty string in my select.

Comment: you missed echo. put <?php echo $key ?> and <?php echo $value ?>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to write `echo`

```
<option value="<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $value; ?></option>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use php, use "echo" to display a value:

```
<select name="countries">
  <option value=""></option>
  <?php foreach($country_list as $key => $value): ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $value; ?></option>
  <?php endforeach ?>
</select><br>
```